# Loop through all csv files in folder and edit each file with the same code

Tags: r, csv, lapply

I want to loop through all my.csv files in a folder to edit all files in similar manner. This what I wrote for a single file and I want the exact same to happen to all files in the folder and write a new .csv file with the original name.

```
mydata <- read.csv("\\\\dcf.network\\data\\\\R\\Test Folder", header=FALSE)
mydata$V1 <- mydata$V2[3]
mydata <- mydata[!(mydata$V9 == ""), ]
columns <- c("V1","V2","V3","V4","V9")
mydata <- mydata[columns]
```

I currently tried to code it like this:

```
files <- list.files(full.names = TRUE)

lapply(files, function(i) {
  for (i in 1:length(files))
    data <- read.csv(files[i])
  data$V1 <- data$V2[3]
  data <- data[!(data$V9 == ""), ]
  columns <- c("V1","V2","V3","V4","V9")
  data <- data[columns]
  write.csv(data, file = files[i])
})
```

Comment: use lapply or a loop. not both at the same time

Comment: It is very important to include a reproducible example if you want people gives you a well detailed answer. In this case, you should find some way to share one of your csv files (randomizing some values if you think it would be necessary).